# How use LogEventInfo and LogMessageGenerator/IFormatProvider together in a Log method?

Tags: nlog

The event context layout renderer gets its parameters from the LogEventInfo parameter, for example:
http://nlog-project.org/wiki/Event-context_layout_renderer

However the LogEventInfo parameter is available in only 2 of the Log method signatures:

```
     public void Log(Type wrapperType, LogEventInfo logEvent)
     public void Log(LogEventInfo logEvent)
```

How can I pass the LogEventInfo if I want to use other Log methods, for example:

```
     public void Log<T>(LogLevel level, IFormatProvider formatProvider, T value)
     public void Log(LogLevel level, LogMessageGenerator messageFunc)
     public void LogException(LogLevel level, [Localizable(false)] string message, Exception ecxception)
```

Assuming this is not possible in NLog 2.0, what workarounds are available?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The latter Log methods you have listed are really just convenience methods over the first two.  In other words, they just construct `LogEventInfo`s themselves.  When you use the first two methods, you're circumventing the convenience for the sake of greater customization.

To recreate the functionality of the convenience methods, you have to play around a bit with `LogEventInfo`.

```
// instead of..
Log<T>(LogLevel level, IFormatProvider formatProvider, T value)
// use:
LogEventInfo.Create<T>(LogLevel level, <log name>, IFormatProvider formatProvider, T value)

// instead of..
Log(LogLevel level, LogMessageGenerator messageFunc)
// use:
if (Log.IsEnabled(level))
    Log.Log(LogEventInfo.Create(level, Log.Name, messageFunc()));

// instead of..
LogException(LogLevel level, string message, Exception exception)
// use:
LogEventInfo.Create(LogLevel level, <log name>, string message, Exception exception)
```

The plus side of doing it with a `LogEventInfo`, again, is that you can then go on to customize the logging event even further before calling `Log()`.